# How do I set Text to NumberValue value?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I'm trying to make the text always set to a numbervalue but it isn't working.

This is my code in question...

```lua
while true do
    wait(0.2)
    script.Parent.Text = script.Parent.Parent.Amount.Value
end
```

I was expecting for the text to say the number value but it didn't.

Comment: What is the problem? What does it return? Does it throw any errors?

Comment: there donsent seems the be any errors but it just dont work. i was making an money system and it does give you money but the gui dont change to show that

Comment: What appears where the text is supported to be, is it blank?

Comment: it just stuck on 0 when its suppose to update to the number value

Comment: This isn't a problem with the text showing then. Obviously there is more code that is supposed to increment the number somewhere.

Comment: oh well i dont know what else there is to add. do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is in your UI, make sure that you're using a LocalScript and not a Script.

And a good way to do this is to use the [Changed](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/NumberValue#Changed) signal on the NumberValue. It will trigger the connected function every time the value changes, so you can easily keep the text property synchronized with the NumberValue's value. But, because the value is a number, be sure to convert it to a string with the `tostring` function.

So try this :

```lua
local numberValue = script.Parent.Parent.Amount
local label = script.Parent

-- create a helper function to update the text
function updateText()
    label.Text = tostring(numberValue.Value)
end

-- set the text for the first time
updateText()

-- update the text every time the number changes
numberValue.Changed:Connect(updateText)
```

Comment: it still doesent seem to work even though it doesent look like there any errors.
any idea why this happens?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, be more specific. Do you have code that is updating the numbervalue, but the UI isn't updating? How are you changing the numbervalue? Where is this code located? I assumed it was in your UI, but is that true?

Comment: yes the value is updating but the UI dont change to show that. and the code is in the UI text label

Comment: it only updates on death

Comment: It sounds like your code isn't updating the `Amount` NumberValue. It would help if you share the code that updates it.